# yum install local rpm throws error if up to date

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, yum, rpm

When installing rpm packages from local file directory it runs fine the first time

```
sudo yum install packages/* -y --disablerepo=*
```

When the same thing is run the second time as part of automated scripts, it throws an error (exit code 1)

```
packages/package.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I can run yum update (exit code 0)

```
sudo yum update packages/* -y --disablerepo=*
...
No packages marked for update
```

The problem with this is that update will skip the packages that are not installed.

I don't want to ignore exit code if there are any real problems here, and just want to do `install-or-update`. Is there a `rpm -i` equivalent that would achieve that? Please take note that this is done on a group of rpm packages that might at any point include additional ones.

I guess one option would be to iterate over them in a shell script and check if they are installed or not, but then again dependency resolution might become rather painful and it does sound like re-inventing a bike.

**UPDATE:**

`rpm --install` will throw exit code depending on the number of failed packages. 
https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2005-July/msg00071.html

`rpm --freshen` will ignore any rpms that are not installed previously while giving no output at all.

Comment: yum localinstall for installing local package

Comment: @c4f4t0r localinstall is a legacy option. yum install behaves the same given the rpm local file. Same exit code, same error.

https://linux.die.net/man/8/yum

Comment: Why not to use `rpm -F packages/*` for update?

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev same issue as `yum update`. It updates/freshens the packages that are already installed. If the list of packages includes a new one, it will be skipped.

Comment: @JackLeo could you show output for `rpm -F <a new one>.rpm`?

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev I could generate it a tad later, yes, I've only checked that with the manual. https://linux.die.net/man/8/rpm
At the moment I am looking into install via `rpm` directly, and that trows more explicit exit codes. In a case of no updates it trows 3. So I am looking  into it at the moment.

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev added. No output at all. Just ignores the package both if given a list `*.rpm` or explicitly the name of the package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

on my system (centos6, centos7) "yum localinstall" will return code 0 even with "Error: Nothing to do" message, while "yum install" returns 1.

```
sudo yum localinstall packages/* -y --disablerepo=*
```

Anyway you can also check the message result to ignore this as a "normal error" in your automation scripts, like for example using bash:

```
sudo yum install packages/* -y --disablerepo=* 2>&1 | tee /tmp/yum.output
grep -q "Error: Nothing to do" /tmp/yum.output
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  ... code for no error
else 
  ... code for error
fi
```

Comment: Your comment regards `localinstall` exit code seems to be true. Not sure how I got the previous result that mimicked `install`, but seems to be my bad. It's not ideal to rely on legacy option, but then again we're talking about centos/redhat.  

the snippet was something that I was aiming to avoid since you would think it would be a desired option but hey ho...

Comment: Indeed, it looks like a bug that should be submitted to redhat...